# Почему разный результат программы при переборе и вводе конкретного числа

Tags: python, вывод

Есть программа, вычисляющая сумму четных цифр числа, затем вычисляющая сумму цифр на четных позициях числа. Далее программа находит модуль разности этих чисел.
Для примера взято число 15.
Вывод в формате n, m, k, i, где n-сумма четных цифр, m-сумма цифр на четных позициях, k-модуль разности, i-исходное число. На первом скрине вывод при вводе числа 15, на втором при переборе (на числе 15).
[image: вывод при вводе числа 15]

[image: вывод на числе 15 при переборе от 1 до 1000]

Код программы:

```
n = 0
m = 0
for i in range(1, 1000):
    s = str(i)
    for a in range(0, len(s), 1):
        x = int(s[a])
        if x % 2 == 0:
            n = n + x
        else:
            n = n + 0
    for b in range(1, len(s), 2):
        z = int(s[b])
        m = m + z
    k = abs(n - m)
    print(n,m,k,i)
    if k == 11:
        print(i)
```

Почему выводятся разные значения?

Comment: Наверное потому, что перед следующей итерацией цикла n и m не обнуляются

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое!